# How can i put Data from a Form automaticly into an json

Tags: json, forms, datatable, airtable

I created a Form with Airtable. Now i want to import the data into an JSON.

How can i do that?

Here is a screenshot of some test data[enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcb0D.png

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON is just a regularly-structured notation for text data, you can simply write a simple concatenation formula to format each record's fields in the correct format.

The only thing that is not straightforward is [extracting the Image,](https://community.airtable.com/t/formula-to-get-image-attachment-url/15285) for which I'm assuming you want to put the `src` URL in the JSON.

For the case you described, create a new Formula field with the following, being sure that the field names (on the right side of each `:` correctly match the field names in your table:

```
'{
   "project_name" : "' & project_name &'",
   "description"  : "' & description &'",
   "picture"      : "' & IF( {Attachment Field},
  RIGHT(LEFT({Attachment Field}, LEN({Attachment Field}) - 1), LEN(LEFT({Attachment Field}, LEN({Attachment Field}) - 1)) - SEARCH("https://", {Attachment Field}) + 1)
,BLANK()) &'",
   "twitter"      : "' & twitter &'",
   "homepage"     : "' & homepage &'",
   "MINT DATE"    : "' & {MINT DATE} &'",
   "discord"      : "' & discord &'",
   "mint"         : "' & mint &'",
   "Where can we…": "' & {Where can we…} &'",
}'
```